# Github Actions Artifact is taking to much to deploy in Azure Web Apps

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, github-actions, azure-artifacts

I have I'm trying to deploy my app on Azure Web apps. I have a Github Actions I was given by default when connecting my GitHub repository in Azure. The problem is that deploying a single thing takes about 45 minutes to be deployed!! It's so insane the amount of time is giving to be deployed. I see a message like this:

[image]

Any idea of why is this happening or a better way to optimize this?
(By the way, I'm actually deploying a Next.js app)

### This is my Github Actions File:

```
# Docs for the Azure Web Apps Deploy action: https://github.com/Azure/webapps-deploy
# More GitHub Actions for Azure: https://github.com/Azure/actions

name: Build and deploy Node.js app to Azure Web App - app-admin

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - develop
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      AUTH0_CLIENT_ID: ${{ secrets.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID }}
      AUTH0_DOMAIN: ${{secrets.AUTH0_DOMAIN}}
      AUTH0_MANAGEMENT_CLIENT_ID: ${{secrets.AUTH0_MANAGEMENT_CLIENT_ID}}
      AUTH0_MANAGEMENT_CLIENT_SECRET: ${{secrets.AUTH0_MANAGEMENT_CLIENT_SECRET}}
      NEXT_PUBLIC_HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT: ${{secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT}}
      NEXT_PUBLIC_HASURA_GRAPHQL_API_KEY: ${{secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_HASURA_GRAPHQL_API_KEY}}
      NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH0_CLIENT_ID: ${{secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH0_CLIENT_ID}}
      NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH0_DOMAIN: ${{secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH0_DOMAIN}}
      


    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Node.js version
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: '14.x'

      - name: npm install, build, and test
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build --if-present
          npm run test --if-present

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: node-app
          path: .

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: node-app

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: 'app-admin'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_667E58BB348E475EA5F1141747DD1CA9 }}
          package: .
```

Comment: Most people use a Docker image to deploy (single file upload is pretty fast), and you can find examples like https://github.com/Azure/webapps-deploy#sample-workflow-to-build-and-deploy-a-nodejs-app-to-containerized-webapp-using-publish-profile

Answer (score 8):

The upload of 38000 files will take forever. As the logs indicate you can speed up this tremendously by zipping up the contents, uploading that and unzipping the contents on the other end.

```yaml
- run: |
    zip -r node-app.zip .
- name: Upload artifact for deployment job
  uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
  with:
    name: node-app
    path: node-app.zip
```

Then unzip it after downloading the artefact in the 2nd job:

```yaml
- name: Download artifact from build job
  uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
  with:
    name: node-app
- run: |
    unzip node-app.zip
    rm node-app.zip
```

Zip or Tar or any other tool will work and, in some cases, simply storing without compression may be faster depending on the size of the archive (time spent compressing vs time spent uploading/downloading).

Comment: I'm getting the following error when running this, "zip error: Nothing to do! (node-app.zip)". I'm doing this following:

```- name: npm install, build, and test
        run: |
          npm install
          yarn build
          zip node-app.zip .```

Comment: try adding `-r`.

Comment: made our deployment process 7 times faster. KUDOS to you!

Comment: When I try to implement this answer I get invalid YAML errors. Here's what I ended up with. What did I do wrong? https://imgur.com/45K8u1J

Comment: @Mitya You're missing an indentation before "zip" After a `|` the multiline block is indented one extra step.

Comment: Right! Thank you.

Comment: One more issue! Appreciate the help. https://imgur.com/7WJGR0X

Comment: @Mitya Probably wanna add ` -o  overwrite files WITHOUT prompting` to the unzip call.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you [Lex Li](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11182/lex-li) supporting your answer adding the process on how to deploy docker image

The better way is to deploy docker image which is very fast in uploading a single file.
Below is the github link as well as the example code of few docker image deployments.

```
on: [push]

name: Linux_Container_Node_Workflow

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    # checkout the repo
    - name: 'Checkout Github Action'
      uses: actions/checkout@master

    - uses: azure/docker-login@v1
      with:
        login-server: contoso.azurecr.io
        username: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_USERNAME }}
        password: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_PASSWORD }}

    - run: |
        docker build . -t contoso.azurecr.io/nodejssampleapp:${{ github.sha }}
        docker push contoso.azurecr.io/nodejssampleapp:${{ github.sha }} 

    - uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
      with:
        app-name: 'node-rnc'
        publish-profile: ${{ secrets.azureWebAppPublishProfile }}
        images: 'contoso.azurecr.io/nodejssampleapp:${{ github.sha }}'
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I'm gonna test this out and come back for any comments.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `npm install` step, it will take time to upload all files in `node_modules` folder to the target.
I removed that step and it run faster then.
But you need to setup node_module folders on the server first by `npm install`, and the action will only copy js file.

```
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Node.js version
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: '14.x'

      # - name: npm install, build, and test
      #   run: |
      #     npm install
      #     npm run build --if-present
      #     npm run test --if-present
      
      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: node-app
          path: .
```

Answer (score 1):

Use cache instead artefacts.

Caching is used to re-use data/files between jobs or workflows while

Artefacts are used to save files after workflow ended.

Caching works much more faster.

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/caching-dependencies-to-speed-up-workflows

https://github.com/actions/cache

```
- name: Cache node
  uses: actions/cache@v3
  with:
    path: .
    key: ${{ runner.os }}-node-${{ hashFiles('**/package-lock.json') }}
```